# new washer installed in my condo, and water is backing up and overflowing on the floor through the hose

Tags: plumbing

I have a plumber came in last wednesday to replace my faucet in the bathroom shower, because the water coming from the shower, both hot and cold was not mixing properly, he replaced the faucet with a one piece handle faucet. everything seems to be fine. He also installed a new washer for me that is just beside the bathroom and the hose where the water suppose to drain out is escaping on the floor. Are you able to tell me why something like this is happening when the washing machine is releasing the water. Is it that the plumber did not hook up the hose properly,or does this have any connection with fixing the new faucet.

Comment: Where is the water escaping from? some photos might be helpful, since we can't see it from here.

Comment: Is the drain hose from the washer backing out of the drain pipe, then popping back down when the washer is drained? This can be infuriating to figure out because when the machine isn't actively dumping, you'd never know it was doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Older washing machines required 1 1/2” pipe.  Newer machines drain water faster than older-style washers, so you may need to install a 2 inch (50mm) drain or get a washing machine that drains slower, like the old one.

I've seen this problem before.

Comment: I see why draining washers into laundry tubs is a good idea now.  It's a built in resevoir.